# How to pass the date within an array to the database in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have made the following migration in Laravel:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('student_id');
        $table->date('att_date')();
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**My Form in Blade look like this**

```xml
<form method="post" action="{{url('att-sumbit')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <strong>Date : </strong>
      <input class="date form-control"  type="text" id="datepicker" name="att_date[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($students_att as $student)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$student -> id}}</td>
          <td>{{$student -> name}}</td>
          <td>{{$student -> level}}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="student_id[]" value="{{$student -> id}}">
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="status[]">
              <option value="0">No</option>
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </table>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
</script>
```

**and I have made my Controller like this:**

```php
public function sumbit(Request $request)
{
    /* $submit = new Attendance;
    $submit->student_id = $request->get('student_id');
    // $submit->att_date = $request->get('att_date');
    // $submit->status = $request->get('status');
    $submit->save();
    return redirect('att'); */

    $studentID = $request->input('student_id', []);
    $studentDate = $request->input('att_date', []);
    $studentStatus = $request->input('status', []);
    
    $students = [];
    
    foreach ($studentID as $index => $student) {
        $students[] = [
            "student_id" => $studentID[$index],
            "att_date" => $studentDate[$index],
            "status" => $studentStatus[$index],
        ];
    }
    
    $create = Attendance::insert($students);
}
```

so I want when i submit my form, it must be record the same date that i used by date picker to every input that show in the following image to my database
[image]

but when i did this procedure, i got this error **(ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1)** the error in this line in my controller line

```
"att_date" => $studentDate[$index],
```

How can Ii fix this error please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"att_date" => $studentDate[$index],` should be `"att_date" => $studentDate[0]`. You only have one date in that form.

Answer (score 1):

Lets something more simple.

```
@foreach($students_att as $student)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$student -> id}}</td>
      <td>{{$student -> name}}</td>
      <td>{{$student -> level}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="student[student_id][]" value="{{ $student->id }}">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="student[status][]">
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Controller :

```
$students = $request->student;

foreach($students as $key => $value) {
    $students[$key]['att_date'] = $request->att_date[0];
}
   
$create = Attendance::insert($students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the migration from date to timestamp, also use Carbon::parse before inserting it to the database.

```
Carbon::parse($datevariable)
```

Comment: `(ErrorException Undefined offset: 1)` means the key is not defined